# How to run a task when a windows service starts?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, installutil, onstart

I have a windows service and I've written the code to run the task within the OnStart() event:

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            this.DoTask();
        }

private void DoTask()
        {
            Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.OriginalFileProcessor.StartPolling());

            try
            {
                Task.Wait(task1);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.Log.Error("Failed running the task", ex);
            }           
        }
```

The DoTask is a never-ending loop. It will stop only when the service is stopped.

But when I try to start the service, it waits a long time then gives me the below error:

```
Windows could not start the ... service on Local Computer.
Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why are you waiting your task to finish?

I think `Task.Wait` is blocking your current thread, then you're getting timeout while starting your service.

EDIT: You need to remove this block:

```
try
{
    Task.Wait(task1);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    this.Log.Error("Failed running the task", ex);
}
```

`Task.Wait` is indeed blocking your current thread. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635.aspx):

> Task.Wait Method
>
> Waits for the Task to complete execution.

**EDIT 2** Do this instead

```
Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.OriginalFileProcessor.StartPolling()).ContinueWith( t =>
{
     var aggException = t.Exception.Flatten();
     foreach(var ex in aggException.InnerExceptions)
         this.Log.Error("Failed running the task", ex);
}, 
TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

Comment: The waiting is not waiting as such. I mean it will just captures any exceptions from that task.

Comment: The waiting *is* "waiting as such". Your code is sat there, doing nothing, waiting for that task to complete. And it's doing that wait on the same thread that called `OnStart`.

Comment: Check my edit, do it with a task continuation. You cannot check for exceptions during the service start, because as it seems this process takes time and it'll likely give you a timeout.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is, because you are waiting for the `OriginalFileProcessor.StartPolling()` to end, but this never happens. You should move your task instance into an seperate member and not wait for it to finish:

```
private Task m_task = null;

private void DoTask()
{
    try
    {
        m_task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.StartPolling());
    }
    catch
    {
        this.Log.Error("Unable to start task", ex);
        throw;  // Rethrow, so that the OS knows, there was something wrong.
    }           
}

private void StartPolling()
{
    try
    {
        this.OriginalFileProcessor.StartPolling();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.Log.Error("Failed running the task", ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: your catch never catches. It can catch only when you wait on it.

Comment: @TheLight: It should only catch exceptions from [`Task.Factory.StartNew`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439.aspx), not from `StartPolling`. You are starting a service to run async, not to wait for it to finish. Updated the answer.

Comment: Task.Factory.StartNew doesn't return exception. You can capture the exception when waiting on a task. or is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

In the loop you need to check if the service status is "stopping" and exit the loop. You have 5 seconds to do that before the OS decides to kill you.